# No instance for (GHC.Base.Alternative Parser) error running Literate Haskell code

Tags: haskell, literate-programming

I'm trying to execute examples in Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell book (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html).
Even though the examples are in literate haskell, I could launch ghci to load the examples; for example `ghci cipher.lhs` (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/cipher.lhs):

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( cipher.lhs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> let2int 'a'
0
```

However with some examples, because of the changes in ghci, I have some issues;  for example in Parsing.ls in chapter 8, I have `No instance for (Applicative ...)` error.

From https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Migration/7.10 I got hints to remove some of the errors by adding some code.

```
> instance Applicative Parser where
>    pure  = return
>    (<*>) = ap  -- defined in Control.Monad
>
> instance Functor Parser where
>    fmap  = liftM
>
> instance Alternative Parser where
>     (<|>) = mplus
>     empty = mzero
```

However, I couldn't resolve this error message:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Alternative’
```

What's wrong with this, and how to solve this issue? 
The original code that causes the problem is from: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/Parsing.lhs

### Solution

Adding this code works fine:

```
import qualified Control.Applicative as CA
instance CA.Alternative Parser where ...
```

Comment: glad we could finally figure it out together - congrats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right from the [Link](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Migration/7.10) you posted:

> GHC says No instance for (Alternative ...)
>
> A side-effect of the AMP is that Alternative became a super-class of
>   MonadPlus. The easy remedy:
>
> instance Alternative Foo where
>       (<|>) = mplus
>       empty = mzero

so here it should be:

```
import Control.Applicative

instance Alternative Parser where
    (<|>) = mplus
    empty = mzero
```

sadly I cannot tell you exactly if this will do because the links to the books code you did provide don't include the instance for `MonadPlus`

### where do find missing definitions

the easiest way is to use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Alternative) or hayoo - as you can see in the link Hoogle for example will tell you that's in the `base` package and the `Control.Applicative` *namespace*

### dealing with the multiples

Ok my bad again - you should be fine with

```
import Control.Applicative (Alternative())
```

or

```
import qualified Control.Applicative as CA

instance CA.Alternative Parser where ...
```

or by qualifying all the stuff (like using `Parsing.many` instead of just `many`)

again sorry that I cannot give you a 100% waterproof compiling solution - you might have to test a bit (for example I am not 100% sure about the `()` here `import Control.Applicative (Alternative())` and you can probably strip it.

Comment: If you check my original post, you can find that I included the `Alternative Parser` for my addition. I updated the link to show the code that has `MonadPlus` and the error message that I have now.

Comment: @prosseek ok sorry - a simple `import Control.Applicative` should do the trick

Comment: please note that those definitions alone will not help me much (I kindof want the code I could load into ghci myself) - yeah I basically know how to implement `Parser` and all the stuff - but I am to lazy to do this or just copy it from the book myself. But you should really try to deal with these minor annoyances yourself - you sooner or later have to and the compiler  error in this last case is not to hard to understand IMO

Comment: PS: also please don't edit my answer this much - if you are not fine with it add your own and accept it (you can do so - you just have to wait a bit I think)

Comment: Well, I just make the question and answer as simple as possible; I'll update my question to show the correct way to do it.   Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I've also stumbled upon this issue. For those who want adapted version of the module `parsing.lhs` just place in import section:

```
> import qualified Control.Applicative as CA
```

and after type Parser definition this code:

```
> instance Applicative Parser where
>    pure  = return
>    (<*>) = ap  -- defined in Control.Monad
> 
> instance Functor Parser where
>    fmap  = liftM
> 
> instance CA.Alternative Parser where
>    (<|>) = mplus
>    empty = mzero
```

Or take adapted version of the module here https://gist.github.com/myshov/85badeb087c51631aee3

Comment: For those who voted negatively. My motivation for this answer was not making of some sort of duplication, but making ready to go solution, for those who just want to grab adapted version of the module for new version GHCI.